# Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Dependencies\Orchard.Modules.dll' is denied

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am working on a Orchard based project and there I am just looking for design issues as I don't have any idea about `.net` and their frameworks everything was working fine until I got this error

`Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Dependencies\Orchard.Modules.dll' is denied.`

I tried to look into this but since I have no idea what is this I am unable to track this however it appears to me as it is an error of permission or something like that also I logged into portal to check the issue there I found the above mentioned file doesn't exist. if it is causing because it doesn't exists there then how can I fix it as I can't install orchard cms again as I don't have enough permission to do so.

Any suggestion/guidelines to track this issue and fix it up?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: "..the above mentioned file doesn't exist..." Have you reported this as a bug?

Comment: no I haven't as I don't know about what has actually happened may be it is deleted by someone else or like as till yesterday it was working fine.. btw what does this file does? I don't have any idea.

Comment: I suppose it contains base classes for Orchad's modules development, but just guessing.

Comment: The application pool Orchard runs under needs write permissions to the App_Data folder. Orchard copies module dlls from bin folders into App_Data/Dependencies folder so as long as you have given the correct permissions, the dlls should be copied in there automatically

Comment: how could I give permission to App_Data so that it can copy the dlls?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid It depends on which operating system are you running, but you don't specify any.

Comment: working on windows os

Comment: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file/#RunningtheSiteUsingIIS